# Select Data from one end based on many end

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables with a one to many relationship as shown below. What I would like to do is select all the data from "tblOne" based on their relationship to "tblThree".

So without having a query to get all tblTwoIDs I would like to select from tblOne where tblThreeID equals an "Inputed Value"

Hope this makes sense,

Thanks
Ben

**tblOne**

tblOneID

data

tblTwoID

---

**tblTwo**

tblTwoID

data

tblThreeID

---

**tblThree**

tblThreeID

data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tblOne.*  -- use "SELECT DISTINCT tblOne.*" to avoid duplicate results
FROM tblOne
    INNER JOIN tblTwo
        ON tblOne.tblTwoID = tblTwo.tblTwoID
    INNER JOIN tblThree
        ON tblTwo.tblThreeID = tblThree.tblThreeID
WHERE tblTwo.tblThreeID = 42  -- replace "42" with the id you want to find
```

If you don't need to ensure that the records exist in `tblThree` then you don't need to join to it at all:

```
SELECT tblOne.*  -- use "SELECT DISTINCT tblOne.*" to avoid duplicate results
FROM tblOne
    INNER JOIN tblTwo
        ON tblOne.tblTwoID = tblTwo.tblTwoID
WHERE tblTwo.tblThreeID = 42  -- replace "42" with the id you want to find
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use join, for example:

```
SELECT t1.data,t3.data FROM t1,t3 WHERE t1.id = td.id AND id = #
```

Comment: Its not as simple a join as that though as far as I can see. I have been trying to use a JOIN but with no luck. For instance you are comparing t1.id against an ID but I need to get data from tblOne when they are in a category from table two which is in a series from tableThree.

Any suggestions on how the join should look?